# Push notification badge is not being displayed

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Now i am receiving push notifications and have not seen any badge above the icon of app yet. Is there a way to count unread push notifications automatically if server does not send number of them?

Comment: Nope, I believe the only options you have are to do the count server side or just increment the count each time you receive a push notification

Comment: @Hodson Do you mean count them before user taps on the notification? If so how can I deal with them before user taps?

Comment: Yeah but it only really works if the app is in the foreground I believe. You can "catch" the notification in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` and then increment the count there.